# How to parse string to give certain piece of text

Tags: java, regex, parsing, xpath

I have the following pieces of text:

`/explanation/NodeExplanations/NodeExplanation[ID='/Temporary/EIC/EICWorksheetPP/Line2Sum']/ExplanationText`

`/explanation/NodeExplanations/NodeExplanation[ID='/Return/ReturnData/Summation/Line2Sum']/ExplanationText`

How can I parse this to give me just :

`/Temporary/EIC/EICWorksheetPP/Line2Sum`

`/Return/ReturnData/Summation/Line2Sum`

How can this be accomplished in Java?
I can use regex, xpath, String expressions or anything but the most efficient. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: wawek shows you one possibility. beside of that try to introduce yourself in Regular expressions.

Comment: @StefanBeike this problem looks like it'll be a good candidate for a regex solution

Comment: Regex could look like this: [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/qO8nD1/1)

Comment: you can do it with regular expressions...but indexOf is more efficient in java... read this interesting [article](http://vanillajava.blogspot.it/2012/01/regex-vs-indexof-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string has always such format then you can simply accomplish this by:

```
String s = "/explanation/NodeExplanations/NodeExplanation[ID='/Temporary/EIC/EICWorksheetPP/Line2Sum']/ExplanationText";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("[ID='")+5, s.indexOf("']")));
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks. Question, what is the '5' for? I'd like to understand what you did here

Comment: Try to execute it without 5 and you will find out ;) It's just the number which stands for `[ID='` length - the part that we don't want to have in fetched substring.